# My properties with Many relationships must use ICollection to support LazyLoading in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net, orm, entity-framework-4.1

I'm found this Microsoft Article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715126%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that says:

**A navigation property that represents the "many" end of a relationship must return a type that implements System.Collections.Generic.ICollection of T, where T is the type of the object at the other end of the relationship.**

My properties with Many relationships must use ICollection to support LazyLoading in Entity Framework 4.1?

Instead if i'm using IList, the Lazy Loading doesn't occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph you're quoting doesn't say anything about lazy loading and is under "For change tracking proxies", so I can't see why it should be relevant for lazy loading.

But IList implements ICollection, so it shouldn't be a problem anyway.